# Htaccess Mod Rewrite Not working for Pretty URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I feel like such a tool for having to post this question, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to resolve my issue. (I've also read/tried previous posts but none have helped me)

I'm trying to turn https://mywebsite.com/article.php?slug=pretty-url to https://mywebsite.com/article/pretty-url

The problem I'm having is the `$_GET` method is not recognizing the slug, so it's giving me a 404 error. The slug is definitely in my database. I'm not sure why I cannot retrieve it.

Below is my htaccess code and my php code to call the page.

Htaccess Code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect www urls to non-www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://mywebsite.com/$1 [L]

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

#Pretty URL for Blog
RewriteRule ^article/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) article.php?slug=$1


#Rewrite for certain files with .php extension
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php
RewriteRule ^services$ services.php
RewriteRule ^portfolio$ portfolio.php
RewriteRule ^blogs$ blogs.php
RewriteRule ^tutorials$ tutorials.php
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php
RewriteRule ^privacy-policy$ privacy-policy.php
RewriteRule ^terms-of-service$ terms-of-service.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap$ sitemap.php
</IfModule>
```

PHP Code on the article.php page:

```
//Get the blog. Only blogs that are published
$slug = $_GET['slug'];
$publish = intval(1);

//Query the database
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE publish = $publish AND slug = $slug";   


//Execute the query
$stmt = $db->query($sql); 
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Try changing the SQL to `"SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE publish = '$publish' AND slug ='$slug'"`

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic The good news is I'm not getting the 404, but a web page with the url in the browser, but it's not pulling any of the content from the database.

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes it takes a while for a browser to take effect with htaccess files. Try clearing your cache or switching browser and testing it on there! :)

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic could the problem now exist in my htaccess code?

Comment: possibly. I have you tried doing what I said above??

Comment: Cleared cache and opened in different browsers, but still nothing. I hope the browser will update from the htaccess.

Comment: then the problem is more than likely in your code. Unfortunately, I'm not an expert in htaccess, try modifying your question to get attention from more people in the forum :)

Comment: Sure will. Thanks for putting me on the right track!

Comment: The one thing I noticed is that `([0-9a-zA-Z]+)` will not capture `pretty-url` because the group doesn't allow for hyphens. Change that to `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` and add `[L]` to the end of that line. Also, for the sake of doing things properly, remove the second and third calls to `RewriteEngine On`.

Comment: @MikeRockett This solved my problem!!!! GENIUS!!! Thank you! I can only up vote your answer. The site won't let me accept it as the correct answer. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer below for you to mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`([0-9a-zA-Z]+)` will not capture `pretty-url` because the group doesn't allow for hyphens. Change that to `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` and add `[L]` to the end of that line.

Also, for the sake of doing things properly, remove the second and third calls to `RewriteEngine On`.

Answer (score 0):

Never apologise for a question! If you're stuck, we will try to help.

What you need in your htaccess is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /article.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

That should change your url to https://mywebsite.com/pretty-url.html

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was trying to remove the page extension altogether. Not add .html. Mike Rockett's comment helped me out. Thanks for trying to help. Really appreciate your willingness to help. :)

Comment: No problem @Soletwosole, we can always write a rule to remove .html also. However, if the problem is now sorted, that's great! :)